# OpenSearch DSL case statement

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, opensearch

I'm working with OpenSearch data, utilizing the OS DSL JSON formatted query language.

The data set of devices that I'm querying against is as follows. I want to use case statement logic to create an inferred data field. Essentially, I am taking 15+ states and applying logic to create an inferred state, reducing the number of states to 4 so it is less confusing to the customer.

| Device | State | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Unavailable | High Temp |
| 12346 | Available | Not Provided |
| 12347 | Unavailable | Not Logged In |
| 12348 | Preinitialized | Startup |
| 12349 | Unavailable | Startup |
| 12350 | Start | Startup |

I would typically approach this in SQL with a case statement.

```
CASE
    WHEN State='Unavailable' AND Reason='High Temp' OR Reason='Not Logged In' THEN 'Attention'
    WHEN State='Active' THEN 'Active'
    WHEN State='Available' THEN 'Available'
    WHEN State='Unavailable' OR State='Start' OR State='Preinitialized' THEN 'Unavailable' //All reasons not defined
END AS NewState
```

How can this be achieved in an OpenSearch DSL query? The 'must', 'must_not', 'should' logic doesn't appear to provide a means to create multiple buckets in in a new field.